# F# Function programming

Tags: function, f#

> 1. Deﬁne the function add10, which takes an integer argument, adds 10 to it, and returns the result.
> 2. Deﬁne the function add20, which uses add10 to add 20 to a given integer. (add20 is not allowed to use “+".)

I am unsure if I am thinking too hard about this and there is a simpler solution like just adding another function he is not asking for, as he didn't specify whether I could or couldn't but only need to use the add10 and add20 functions alone, but I cannot figure out how to add the 20 without an addition sign to the outcome of add10.

Whenever I use just the `add20` function it only whatever integer following it by 2.

Code and output as follows:

```
> let add10 x = x + 10;;
val add10 : x:int -> int

> add10 2;;
val it : int = 12

> let add20 add10 = add10 * 2;;
val add20 : add10:int -> int

> add20 3;;
val it : int = 6

> let j = 2 |> add10 |> add20;;
val j : int = 24
```

Comment: Try changing add20 to `let add20 add10 n = n |> add10 |> add10;;`, currently, you're trying to multiply the function by 2, which doesn't make much sense (unless it's some special f# syntax I'm not aware of)

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it perfectly. I feel like I was thinking, in some manner, it would have multiplied the 10 by 2 in `add10` for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```ml
> let add20 add10 = add10 * 2;;
```

In this declaration, you are saying that `add20` is a function which takes a parameter named `add10`, and returns the value `add10 * 2`. If you used a different name for the parameter, perhaps it would be clearer that this function simply multiplies its argument by 2:

```ml
> let add20 x = x * 2;;
> add20 33;;
val it : int = 66
```

The fact that the parameter is named `add10` does not mean you are using the function `add10` which has the same name; note from the type signature `add20 : add10:int -> int` that the parameter `add10` is expected to be an `int`, not a function.

You seem to have come up with the basic idea of how to solve this problem, which is that the `add20` function should work by doing `add10` twice. The problem is that `add10 * 2` does not mean *"do the function `add10` twice"*, it means *"multiply the number `add10` by 2"*, which is not what you intended.

---

What you really want to do is *call the function twice*, where the output of the first call is used as the input to the second call. You already seem to be aware of the **pipe forwards** operator `|>`, so you could use this:

```ml
> let add20 x = x |> add10 |> add10;;
> add20 33;;
val it : int = 53
```

Or if you look at it another way, what you want is to take the function `add10` and [compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) it with itself to define a new function. If you are familiar with the **function composition** operator `>>`, you can write:

```ml
> let add20 = add10 >> add10;;
> add20 55;;
val it : int = 75
```